# Select Distinct with multi field

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I have created a query that searches events by name. The result list years of event with same name (10/12/2012 to 04/30/2013). My question is how can I make my query just show the events have same name within the year that I want select.

For example: I just want see this month or this year events that have same name.

Query:

```
SELECT
    UserField03, GageNumber, GageType, LastCheckOutDate, CurrentLocation 
FROM 
    Gages
WHERE 
    GageNumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT Gages.GageNumber
                   FROM Gages 
                   INNER JOIN Events ON Gages.GageID = Events.GageID
                   WHERE (Name = 'Returned to Cal')
                  ) 
ORDER BY 
    LastCheckOutDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT UserField03, GageNumber, GageType, LastCheckOutDate, CurrentLocation
FROM Gages INNER JOIN
(SELECT GageID FROM Events eo WHERE eo.Name 
    IN(SELECT e.Name FROM Events e WHERE e.DateOfEvent BETWEEN '2012-10-12' AND '2013-04-30' AND e.Name='Returned to Cal'
    GROUP BY e.Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AND  e.DateOfEvent BETWEEN '2012-10-12' AND '2013-04-30')  EveAlias
ON Gages.GageID=EveAlias.GageID
```

In the most nested subselect you are getting names of events, which satisifies the date and name condition and whose name occurs more than one time (`HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)` in the defined period. In the outer select you are getting `GageId` of such events, so you can perform the final join with `Gages`.